# Microservices in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jwt, seneca

I'm trying to develop a microservice in Node.js. I wish to develop a microservice for authentication using jsonwebtokens. I'm trying to make it using SenecaJS. Shall I use any other framework/tool? What should be my approach? Unable to find proper documentations. What seneca plugins can I use?

Answer (score 0):

I use [seneca-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seneca-jwt). Very good plugin.